# Informatica update target table

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a requirement in which I need to update the target table in informatica.
The data is coming hourly and a similar id can contain updated columns from multiple rows.

Consider below scenario, if there are 5 rows coming for 2 different id, the target column should have only 2 rows with latest changes.

Source:

| emp_id | emp_sal | emp_dept | mobile |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10000 |  | 672516 |
| 1 | 10000 | HR | 672516 |
| 1 | 15000 | HR | 672516 |
| 2 | 30000 |  | 931512 |
| 2 | 30000 | Admin | 931512 |

The target should be

| emp_id | emp_sal | emp_dept | mobile |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15000 | HR | 672516 |
| 2 | 30000 | Admin | 931512 |

The target should have only latest data with aggregation of single id.

The actual source table has many records and contains 15-20 columns.
I tried using dynamic lookup putting the conditions for all columns but performance is the concern.

Could anyone provide a good strategy to achieve this in informatica powercenter or an improved version of lookup.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this using simple sorter aggregator. But you need to decide how you will determine latest row. Based on salary or some data like last change date etc.?
I will assume there is a field called `last_change_date` and give you the mapping.

1. create a sorter trnsf - sort on `emp_id, last_change_date descending` in this order. You can use any other column which will give you latest data.
2. next use an aggregator - and group by `emp_id`. All other ports will be pass through.
3. While inserting into target, you can use a normal lookup on target joining on `emp_id`. This will give you insert update flag - if it exist in target then update else insert.
4. use update strategy to update the target.
5. The target definition should have `emp_id` defined as key.

This will pick latest row per one `emp_id` and you have the target with latest data.